# Running two programs from command line with a wait

Tags: ubuntu

I want to run two different programs from the command line in Ubuntu. Each has its own set of arguments. However, I want to wait for 5 seconds between launching the first program and the second. How can I enforce this wait?

Thus far, I have:

```
$ ./Program1 -a -b && ./Program2 -c -d
```

But I need to insert a wait between the two programs, and I want to do this all in one line on the command line. Is this possible?

Comment: What does this have to do with C++?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible:

> ./Program1 -a -b && sleep 5 && ./Program2 -c -d